# Javascript Not Working/Loading

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried working with some code from JSFiddle, and it is working fine.

Although when I try and implement it in HTML, it doesn't work the same way.

Here's what I have so far:

**Javascript:**

```
var checker = document.getElementById('checkme');
var sendbtn = document.getElementById('sendNewSms');
checker.onchange = function(){
    if(this.checked){
        sendbtn.disabled = false;
    } else {
        sendbtn.disabled = true;
    }

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<h1>Button should be enabled if at least one checkbox is checked</h1>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkme"/><input type="submit" name="sendNewSms" class="inputButton" id="sendNewSms" value=" Send " disabled/>
```

Comment: So what errors are you getting in the browser's console?

Comment: This one:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null

Comment: On a sidenote: `sendbtn.disabled = !this.checked;`

Comment: Yeah, I want to enable to button, if the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the script inside window.onload event to make sure that the dom elements are available.

```js
window.onload = function() {
var checker = document.getElementById('checkme');
var sendbtn = document.getElementById('sendNewSms');
checker.onchange = function(){
   if(this.checked) sendbtn.disabled = true;
   else sendbtn.disabled = false;
}
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkme"/>
<input type="submit" name="sendNewSms" class="inputButton" id="sendNewSms" value=" Send " />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript needs to be in `<script>` tags. It's not clear if they are or not by your question, so I'll assume they're not:

```
<html>
<head><title>Still learning</title></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
  var checker = document.getElementById('checkme');
  var sendbtn = document.getElementById('sendNewSms');
  checker.onchange = function(){
    if(this.checked){
        sendbtn.disabled = false;
    } else {
        sendbtn.disabled = true;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<h1>Button should be enabled if at least one checkbox is checked</h1>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkme"/><input type="submit" name="sendNewSms" class="inputButton" id="sendNewSms" value=" Send " disabled/>
</body>
</html>
```

Read up on html basics

Comment: Here's the Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/n9z5D/

I've already added the script tags, as you've mentioned. Still not working.

Comment: @user3437020 The fiddle works fine. I guess you have not added any html structure at all? see my updated example.

Answer (score 1):

> This one: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null

Your javascript is executing before the html finishes completely loading.
This is why `document.getElementById('checkme')` is returning `null`. Put the function into a `window.onload` and insert the script into the `<head>` like this.

```
<html>
<head><title>Still learning</title>
<script>
 window.onload = function() {
  var checker = document.getElementById('checkme');
  var sendbtn = document.getElementById('sendNewSms');
  checker.onchange = function(){
    if(this.checked){
        sendbtn.disabled = false;
    } else {
        sendbtn.disabled = true;
    }
  }
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Button should be enabled if at least one checkbox is checked</h1>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkme"/><input type="submit" name="sendNewSms" class="inputButton" id="sendNewSms" value=" Send " disabled/>
</body>
</html>
```

It should work now. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/n9z5D/